# osm2pgsql import crashed!

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, postgresql, php, osm2pgsql

I am currently importing a bz2 country file into PostgreSQL 9.1 database for Nominatim 2 using its `setup.php` that runs `osm2pgsql`.

After processing the nodes. it seems to be stuck at a certain spot for hours without any changes and both CPU/memory usage for the server went down to idle levels.

Any idea what happened? The full output can be found [here](http://paste.laravel.com/5yB).

**Output Snippet**

```
                            addgeometrycolumn
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 public.import_polygon_error.prevgeometry SRID:4326 TYPE:GEOMETRY DIMS:2
(1 row)

                            addgeometrycolumn
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 public.import_polygon_error.newgeometry SRID:4326 TYPE:GEOMETRY DIMS:2
(1 row)

CREATE INDEX
CREATE TABLE
CREATE INDEX
CREATE SEQUENCE
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
CREATE INDEX
CREATE TABLE
ALTER TABLE
Partitions
```

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using [imposm](http://imposm.org/docs/imposm/latest/) due to crashes with osm2pgsql. There's a pretty good step by step guide [here](https://github.com/mapbox/osm-bright) for importing an osm data set.

Hope this helps out

Comment: Thanks, I'm in the process of checking imposm out! As for the setup done by Nominatim, how should I combine that with the import using imposm?